# Accessing images from google cloud bucket (smiliar to folder)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to load all images I have stored in a bucket with a python script. To load the locally stored images I'm using the following code.

```
 images_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'image_data')
 images = []
 for each in os.listdir(images_dir):
    images.append(os.path.join(images_dir,each))
```

Is there a way to access buckets in a folder-like style?

Comment: What will you be doing with the images once you have "loaded" them?

Comment: I convert them to a tensor
 all_images = tf.convert_to_tensor(images, dtype = tf.string)

is the next step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load all images, you need to list all the available files from google cloud storage bucket using `list_blobs().` Then you can download the objects in a loop. Here is an example:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket("YOUR_BUCKET_NAME")
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix="YOUR_FOLDER_CONTAINS_IMAGES")
images = []

for idx, bl in enumerate(blobs):
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    data = bl.download_as_string()
    images.append(data)
```

Don't forget to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable for authentication.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Why "if idx == 0: continue"?

Comment: @asbovelw it is actually to skip the header file

Comment: What do you mean with "header file"? When I use the code, this "if" only skips the first file it finds, so I assume you mean this; but, why would you skip the first file? For example I have 3 images there and using your code with the "if" just downloads the last 2 ones.

Comment: sorry @asbovelw , that is not header file. I was out of focus. It is to skip the folder path only. For example, your target folder is gs://bucket/images, which contains: a.txt, b.txt. the `blobs` will contain gs://bucket/images in the 1st index. So, it will be [gs://bucket/images, gs://bucket/images/a.txt, gs://bucket/images/b.txt]. Since it is not the file. I skip it. If you print out `print(bl)`, it will be clear.

Comment: it aims to skip folder path itself instead of processing it, not skipping any file.

Comment: Ah I see, now. At first I put the files directly in the "root folder", and the "prefix" I put was just the common part of the file names they shared, not their path without the file name, so the "enumerate" didn't list anything else than the files. I tried now putting the files in an empty "subfolder" and putting its name in "prefix" and it works as you said. Thanks @Sugimiyanto suma

Comment: Nice. Glad to hear that @asbovelw.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. List the objects in a bucket using the [GET Bucket API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects)
2. Load each one using the [GET Object API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects)

Answer (score 0):

1. I would recommend to use google-cloud-storage [Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/) to access and manipulate bucket objects. Here you have Python [Google Cloud Storage SDK examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/38ccb43060225fe61f99f53ff4dccc2ceeffd84f/storage/cloud-client). [Here is another example for Cloud Functions for accessing object](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/38ccb43060225fe61f99f53ff4dccc2ceeffd84f/functions/imagemagick)
2. Another option is to mount your bucket as folder using [gcfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse)

Using SDK please be aware that object gs://your-bucket/abc/def.txt is just an object that happens to have "/" characters in its name. There is no "abc" directory; just a single object with the given name. [Here is documentation that explains how directories work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork).