# Load folder of images (dataset) stored in Google Cloud Storage using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, google-colaboratory

I am trying to load a folder of images from Google Cloud Storage bucket into a Python script (version 3.9) using different way but didn't work! My folder contains approximately 930,000 images in path: `buket-name/main-folder/image-folder`.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131784/accessing-images-from-google-cloud-bucket-smiliar-to-folder), and it takes a long time without any result.
I define the Google credential and service account, but still no response!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **without any result** is not a programming problem. Show your code and the problem/error/results.

Comment: @JohnHanley Or when the  run finish and I try to print the length of images array it's equal to 0. what should I do?

Comment: You have not included any code in your question.

Comment: Are you really need the 930k images in your collab machine?

Comment: @JohnHanley Ok, I try to load images from gcs to use it as deep learning model datasets. I used the solution posted there [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131784/accessing-images-from-google-cloud-bucket-smiliar-to-folder)  , So, when I try to print the bl value (refers to blob) it prints something like this : **<Blob: Bucket-name, main-folder/image-folder/Image1.jpg, num>** and the "data" variable is long string value in format like this 00/**/**/..... how can I manipulate this value as image? to display it -for example- Thank you in advance.